# Enumeration in continuous text

Tags: enumerate

I am trying to use enumeration in a text. It would look like in this example:

> "Among pets the most common ones are (i) dogs, (ii) cats and (iii)
> rabbits.
> (i) Dogs are very nice animals. However they need to be walked several
> times a day....[continuous long passage spreading over multiple lines]
>
> (ii) Cats are often considered easier animals but....
>
> [...]
> "

I guess I will not need to refer to each passage more than once, so I can also just type out the brackets and the numbers. However, just typing "(ii)" doesn't seem very nice when using LaTeX. Is there an easy and more elegant way to enumerate like in the example?

Comment: You need to use an environment for numbering such as `enumerate`. Please [check this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures) for understand it better. And please add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your questions.

Comment: @Aradnix sorry I did not see the page before - i think this provides what i am looking for. However since I do not know the code i also did not know what kind of MWE to provide...Since this seems to be quite basic I guess its better to delete the questino.

Comment: Don't be fearful, you don't have to delete anything, just be right with the conventions of the site to ask questions, and always add an MWE, check out the link I sent you before. And remember that no one was born knowing things. We always can learn.

Comment: I hope both answers too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Among pets the most common ones are \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)]
\item dogs,\label{item:dogs}
\item cats and \label{item:cats}
\item rabbits.\label{item:rabbits}
\end{enumerate*}

\ref{item:dogs} Dogs are very nice animals. However they need to be walked several times a day\ldots [continuous long passage spreading over multiple lines]

\ref{item:cats} Cats are often considered easier animals but\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image: Result using enumitem]

Comment: If the last word before the last is always the same, you can set it globally with `itemjoin=and`, which saves having to type it each time.

Comment: You can use `shortlabels` options so that `\begin{enumerate*}[(i)]` is enough.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution with package `paralist`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
    \begin{document}
    Among pets the most common ones are 
        \begin{inparaenum}[(i)]
            \item dogs, 
            \item cats and 
            \item rabbits.
        \end{inparaenum}

        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item Dogs are very nice animals. However they need to be walked several times a day\ldots [continuous long passage spreading over multiple lines]
            \item Cats are often considered easier animals but\ldots 
            \item \ldots
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Result with paralist]

Answer (score 3):

I would do this a bit differently. Rather than using a list environment for the first occurrences of the animal names, I would use it for the main description and use references for the initial list. One advantage of this is that TeX will issue warnings if you forget to actually say anything about any of the animals in your initial list. But mostly, this just seems to me the more natural way to do it since it is the descriptions which you really want formatted as a list.

In the following, I use `enumitem` to define a new list. I then define a new environment `animals` for the main list of descriptions, and a new command `\animalref` to use for the initial listing. The usual `\item` is redefined within the `animals` environment in order to accept a tag (the group of animals) which is used to automatically set a label we can reference in the definition of `\animalref`. The upshot of this is as follows:

- environment `animals` takes one optional argument. If the optional argument is used, its contents are basically passed to `enumitem`'s `enumerate` environment. You only need to worry about this if you want to change something about the list format.
- `\item[]{}` **within `animals` only** takes one optional and one mandatory argument. The optional one is the usual optional argument for `\item`. The mandatory one is a tag such as `dogs` or `cats`.
- `\animalsref{}` takes one mandatory argument. This argument is intended to correspond to the tag set for the item in the main list e.g. `dogs` or `cats`. It will typeset the relevant item label followed by the tag itself. So you'll get e.g. '(i) dogs' or '(ii) cats'. If you pass a tag which does not occur in the main list, you'll get question marks e.g. '?? rabbits' and TeX will output a warning.

This sounds a lot more complicated than it really is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xparse, kantlipsum}
\newlist{animalslist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[animalslist]{label=(\roman*)}
\global\let\olditem\item
\NewDocumentCommand\animalsitem { o m }{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \olditem\label{animals:#2}}{%
    \olditem[#1]\label{animals:#2}}%
  }
\newenvironment{animals}[1][]{%
  \let\item\animalsitem
  \begin{animalslist}[#1]%
  }{%
  \end{animalslist}%
}
\newcommand*\animalsref[1]{\ref{animals:#1} #1}
\begin{document}
  Among pets the most common ones are \animalsref{dogs}, \animalsref{cats} and \animalsref{rabbits}.
  \begin{animals}
    \item{dogs} Some people consider dogs very nice animals. However they need to be walked several times a day and tend to eat your shoes.

    \kant[1]

    \item{cats} Cats are nicer animals but need to be worshipped several times a day and tend to walk over your keyboard.

    \kant[2]
  \end{animals}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, '??' show that I've not remembered to actually say anything about rabbits, while the cats and dogs get their appropriate labels. Compile twice to stabilise the references.

[image: cats and dogs but no rabbits]